# Proof for torque=force*perpendicular distance to line of action of force

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, torque

I want to derive from first principles the proof for magnitude of torque about a point O = perpendicular distance from O to the line of action of the force * magnitude of the force. I want to derive this result for a general 3-D case for any arbitrary point O and force ***F*** .
I need to prove this mathematically without knowing the cross-product magnitude in terms of the angle between the vectors..... that is given any force F = Fx i + Fy j + Fz k and any point O and using torque= r cross F & using the determinant expansion for the same & also the expressions for magnitude of a vector, I need to prove this.... In other words, I need to prove that the magnitude of the cross-product is indeed F*r*sin(theta

Comment: What first principles do you want to start from? Because that's pretty much the definition of torque...

Comment: @PranavHosangadi Conventionally, it's $\vec r\times \vec F$ not $\vec F\times \vec r$ where $\vec r$ is the distance from the origin to where the force is applied, not the perpendicular distance.

Comment: @David Z  I need to prove this mathematically without knowing the cross-product magnitude in terms of the angle between the vectors..... that is given any force F = Fx i + Fy j + Fz k and any point O and using torque= r cross F & using the determinant expansion for the same & also the expressions for magnitude of a vector, I need to prove this.... In other words, I need to prove that the magnitude of the cross-product is indeed F*r*sin(theta) ...

Comment: @K.R.Manish in that case you should probably head over to [math.SE] and ask how to prove that the magnitude of the cross product $\vec{a}\times\vec{b}$ is $ab\sin\theta$. It sounds like your question is fundamentally of a mathematical nature, there's no physics in it. (Of course, first you should check whether e.g. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product) provides a proof.)

Comment: IIRC, there was a proof in Marion that $a\cdot b=ab\cos \theta$, the cross product formula should be similar.

Answer (score 4):

Torque is defined as $$\vec{\tau} \equiv \vec{r} \times \vec{F}$$

The cross product is defined to satisfy the following property

$$\left| \vec{a} \times \vec{b} \right| = ab \sin \theta$$

Therefore

$$\left| \vec{\tau} \right| = \left| \vec{r} \times \vec{F} \right| = F r \sin \theta$$

But $r \sin \theta$ is the perpendicular distance. This completes the proof. Note the lack of dependence on the choice of origin.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by lack of dependence on choice of origin? $\vec{r}$ is the vector from the "reference point" to the point of application of the force. The reference point can be anywhere, even though one *usually* takes it to be the rotation axis.

Comment: Although the position vector is origin-dependent, it seems to me that $r \ sin \theta$ is always perpendicular to $F$. The exact value depends on the choice of origin, but the perpendicularity should not. Does that sound right?

Comment: @EtaZetaTheta  that is alright.... But I need to prove this mathematically without knowing the cross-product magnitude in terms of the angle between the vectors..... that is given any force F = Fx i + Fy j + Fz k and any point O and using torque= r cross F & using the determinant expansion for the same & also the expressions for magnitude of a vector, I need to prove this.... In other words, I need to prove that the magnitude of the cross-product is indeed F*r*sin(theta) ...

Comment: @K.R.Manish  Could you clarify that in your question?